# Error while trying to create a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I've been trying to run the following macro to create a pivot table out of a range from another sheet of data and I can´t seem to make it work.

```
Sub topc()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("TOP C").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "TOP C"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Complaints!R1C1:R3000C32", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="TOP C!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=6


      ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Recurrence")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

      ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Subtype Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

      With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type Inquiry")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Value"), "Sum of Value", xlSum


End Sub
```

I keep getting error "Invalid Procedure or Argument" in this area:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
       "Complaints!R1C1:R3000C32", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
       TableDestination:="TOP C!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
       DefaultVersion:=6
```

and keeps telling me xlDatabase = 1, idk if thats the problem. PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: The use of `ActiveWorkbook` may be the issue. `ActiveWorkbook` refers to the workbook that is active at the moment that line of code runs. If that is not hte workbook with the pivot cache, that is going to error. Perhaps, `ThisWorkbook` is better, as that refers to the workbook running the code. Better yet, explicitly declare the exact needed workbook to a variable and work with that variable. (Same for `ActiveSheet` btw.)

Comment: Also, split the creation of the pivot cache and the pivot table into two lines... don't chain them together. (IIRC the macro recorder is not helpful here, I think it chains them).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman there is only one workbook open and its the same issue with ```thisworkbook

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using, and what format is the workbook - xls or later?

Comment: @Rory  its .XLSM  and i think its the latest version of excel, not sure since its a corporate laptop and access is pretty limited.

Comment: You've got a space in the sheet name so it should be: `TableDestination:="'TOP C'!R1C1"` rather than `TableDestination:="TOP C!R1C1"`

Comment: This is a step-by-step tutorial on creating pivot tables in VBA and is a good reference for what is missing.  According to this, you need to declare the pivot cache.  https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/

Comment: @Rory that did it!!! thank you very much.